# JMSSerializerBundle and custom normalaizers

Tags: json, api, symfony, serialization, jmsserializerbundle

In our project we are useing **[JMSSerializerBundle](https://github.com/schmittjoh/JMSSerializerBundle)** and for some API responses we need to use **custom normalizers**.

When using standard the Symfony serializer it is working well, but in the JMS-only way of attaching normalizers, it is using the `SubscribingHandler` but it only interats only with a few types like:

- NULL
- string
- boolean
- double
- float
- array

So the question is, does someone know of a solution to have JMS and SYmfony custom normalizers work together?